# Раздача интернет от OPENVPN клиентов на домашнюю сеть

Tags: iptables, openvpn, nat, route

Добрый день. Установил сборку zentyal, в нём есть openvpn клиенты. Настроил, включил, тоннели поднялись.
Далее замучался копаться в настройках, стоит задача просто раздать интернет от OPENVPN туннеля в домашнюю локальную сеть.

```html
root@zentyal:~# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
172.16.100.102  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
192.168.100.1   172.16.100.102  255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun1
192.168.100.102 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.139.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.248 U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.139.64  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.192 U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.139.128 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.192 U     0      0        0 eth0

_____________________________________________________________
root@zentyal:~# ifconfig -a

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:08:a1:94:07:bb
      inet addr:192.168.139.6  Bcast:192.168.139.7  Mask:255.255.255.248
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:7175 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:5342 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:5886712 (5.8 MB)  TX bytes:794041 (794.0 KB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:80:48:57:0a:d4
      inet addr:192.168.1.1  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

eth0:local Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:08:a1:94:07:bb
      inet addr:192.168.139.111  Bcast:192.168.139.127  Mask:255.255.255.192
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

eth0:local2 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:08:a1:94:07:bb
      inet addr:192.168.139.129  Bcast:192.168.139.191  Mask:255.255.255.192
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:2129 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:2129 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:371062 (371.0 KB)  TX bytes:371062 (371.0 KB)

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
      inet addr:192.168.100.101  P-t-P:192.168.100.102  Mask:255.255.255.255
      UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:100
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:336 (336.0 B)

tun1      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
      inet addr:172.16.100.101  P-t-P:172.16.100.102  Mask:255.255.255.255
      UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:25 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:100
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:2100 (2.1 KB)
```

Мне нужно чтобы инернет из туннеля tun1 или tun0 раздавался на интрерфейс eth1.

Да, вот они туннели, в панели на главной указано что подняты и работают, но что толку с них, если я не могу направлять в них трафик?. Настроены естественно как tun при установке в настройках клиента.

Пожалуйста, если кто реально специалист в теме, напишите в виде конкретной пошаговой инструкции, что нужно сделать, интернет уже неделю копаю и на эту тему лишь очень скудная разрозненная информация!

Comment: в [описании](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/iptables/info) одной из использованных вами меток есть ссылка и на lartc и на перевод. конкретные рекомендации для вашего случая находятся в четвёртой главе («правила — база политик маршрутизации»). но для лучшего понимания, вероятно, стоит прочитать и предыдущую, третью главу («введение в iprotue2»).